# Create a button with a link to the nav bar Angular2 Material-Design-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, href, navbar

I'm just learning java and angular 2, in my front end i have a nav that is using material design bootstrap (http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/), in my view i have a nav pill

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#formulario">Formulario</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#documentos">Documentos</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#flujo">Flujo</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <!--      DOCUMENTOS     -->
    <div id="formulario" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <!--      Here i have a dynamyc-form take from a json -->
    </div>

    <!--      DOCUMENTOS     -->
    <div id="documentos" class="tab-pane fade">
        <!--      fields to upload document -->
    </div>

    <!--      FLUJO  -->
    <div id="flujo" class="tab-pane fade">
        <!--      just a table with a list of activities  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically that's the code, the problem is i'm trying to put a button below the tab `formulario` to take me to the next tab `documentos` but when a put the new button with the `href=#documentos` it take me to the tab `documentos` but it doesn´t have the tab `docuemntos` as actived (the tab `documentos` still active).

Sorry by my poor english, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this: [Learning Angular 2: Conditionally add styles to an element](http://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/)

something lik this example

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      <div [class.active]="isActive('new_tab_name')">
        New Tab Name
      </div>
      <div [class.active]="isActive('tab_name')">
        Tab Name
      </div>          
      <button (click)="setActive('new_tab_name')">Toggle style</button>
    </div>
  `
})
class MyApp {

  tabName:string = 'tab_name';

  setActive(tab) {
    this.tabName = tab;
  }

  isActive(tab) {
    return this.tabName == tab;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Edit.

Or maybe, you just have to add the javascript file to the angular-cli, like this example: [Global Library Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation)